# Find a regex statement to delete all occurences of "\" and the subsequent symbol

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a use case where

```
x <- "test - hello\r\n 1...124"
```

and I would like to obtain `"test - hello 1...124`. I am aware that I can use `"gsub("[\r\n]", "", x)"` for this specific case. However, I am wondering how to more generally remove any backslash followed by any symbol (e.g. using something like `"\."` and escaping the backslash). Examples that did not work are

```
gsub("\.", "", x) # error
gsub("\\.", "", x) # escapes "."?
gsub("\\\.", "", x) # error 
gsub("\\\\.", "", x) # ??
...
```

Also I would be very thankful for an explanation as to why this is not working.

Comment: First and foremost, there is no backslash in `"\n"`. There is an LF char here. So what is your question about then? Replacing any newline (LF) char with an `n` char? Replacing each `"\r"` (carriage return, CR) char with an `r` char?

Comment: As stated, I would like to delete `"\r\n"` from my string by specifically deleting any occurrence of `"\"` followed by any symbol

Comment: It is not possible, the  backslash exists in the string literal notation, not in the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the package `strings` you can use `str_squish` to remove not only leading and trailing whitespaces but also whitespaces somewhere in the middle.

```r
x <- "test - hello\r\n 1...124"
stringr::str_squish(x)
#> [1] "test - hello 1...124"
```

---

```
gsub("\\r|\\n","", x)
```

gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am interested in specifically solving this issue using a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you again. However, I would like to do so given any symbol following the `"\"`, not just the specific r or n.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove both newlines (or other escaped characters) and other strings that begin with `\`, you can just include both in the expression:

```
\r|\n|\t|\0|\\.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As mentioned in the comment to the prior solution, I was looking for a general way of doing so that is not specific to `"\n"` etc. Mr Stribizew's answer makes sense, that this would not be obtainable.